# Eclipse: Unable to set language level 8

Tags: eclipse

I have got eclipse "Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)"  on windows 7 running with jdk 8, but I am not able to assign language level 8 for my project and getting compile error for all lambda expressions. Why? There highest level is `1.7`.

Comment: Did you select a Java 8 JDK in Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs?

Comment: Of course. It is included in the System library for the project. In fact, I only have java 8 in the list of installed JREs.